# Вывод промежуточных результатов в многопоточном режиме

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня есть метод, который проивзодит некоторые действия и выводит постепенно результат
Как мне выполнять метод в одном потоке, а результаты выводить в другом  оповещая второй поток из первого по мере появления результатов

```
package model;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Queue;

public class FileManager {

    public static void parseListPath(String parentPath, int depth, String mask) throws IOException {

        File currentPath = new File(parentPath).getAbsoluteFile();

        if (!currentPath.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Cannot access " + currentPath.getPath());
        }

        if (!currentPath.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(currentPath.getPath() + " not a directory");
        }

        if (depth < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("List depth cannot be less than zero");
        }

        Queue<Entry> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        Entry entry = new Entry(0, currentPath);
        do {
            int nextDepth = entry.getDepth() + 1;
            currentPath = entry.getFile();
            if (currentPath.isDirectory()) {
                File[] files = currentPath.listFiles();

                if (files != null) {
                    for (File file : files) {
                        if (nextDepth <= depth && file.isDirectory()) {
                            queue.offer(new Entry(nextDepth, file));
                        }

                        if (mask == null || file.getName().contains(mask))
                            System.out.print(file.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
                    }
                }
            }
            entry = queue.poll();

        } while (entry != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно эту строку `System.out.print(file.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");` вынести в отдельный поток? И еще, вам нужно выводить информацию по всем найденным файлам или что-то можно пропускать?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov да, именно эту строку

Comment: Модель производитель потребитель  гуглите и используете нужную функцию.

Comment: На вторую часть вопроса не ответили

Comment: @AntonShchyrov по всем верным условию if (mask == null || file.getName().contains(mask))

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
class Handle{
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable> heap = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();

    public synchronized Runnable getTask() {
        return heap.poll();
    }

    public synchronized void addTask(Runnable e) {
        heap.add(e);
    }

    public synchronized int size() {
        return heap.size();
    }

    public synchronized boolean isEmpty() {
        return size() == 0;
    }
}
```

Когда нужно добавить задачу, используйте метод `addTask`. Получаете с помощью метода `getTask` - выполнить задачу можно с помощью вызова у экземпляра интерфейса `Runnable` метода `run`.

Если же нужно именно получить объект(в том числе и String):

```
class Handle<T>{
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Supplier<T>> heap = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();

    public synchronized T getNext() {
        return isEmpty() ? null : heap.poll().get();
    }

    public synchronized void add(Supplier<T> e) {
        heap.add(e);
    }

    public synchronized int size() {
        return heap.size();
    }

    public synchronized boolean isEmpty() {
        return size() == 0;
    }
}
```

Тест:

```
Handle<String> h = new Handle<String>();

h.add(() -> "1");
h.add(() -> "2");
h.add(() -> "3");

while(!h.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(h.getNext());
}
```

Вывод:

> 1
>   2
>   3

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно сделать общим для двух потоков экземпляр интерфейса `BlockingQueue`. Тогда ваш класс будет заполнять эту очередь, а другой поток выбирать из нее элементы и выводить на экран.

В коде это будет выглядеть так

```
public class FileManager {
  public static void parseListPath(String parentPath, int depth, String mask, BlockingQueue<Optional<File>> queue) throws IOException {
    ............
    do {
      ......
      if (mask == null || file.getName().contains(mask))
        queue.put(Optional<File>.of(file));  // добавили элемент в очередь
      ............
    } while (entry != null);
    queue.put(Optional<File>.empty());  // добавили пустой элемент в очередь, как признак завершения работы
  }
}
```

Класс для обработки очереди

```
class Consumer implements Runnable {
  private final BlockingQueue<Optional<File>> queue;
  Consumer(BlockingQueue<Optional<File>> q) { queue = q; }
  public void run() {
    try {
      while (true) {  // Бесконечный цикл
        // Извлекаем первый элемент из очереди. Если его нет, то ждем когда появится
        Optional<File> opt = queue.take();
        // если извлекли пустой элемент, то работа окончена и выходим
        if (!opt.isPresent())
          break;
        System.out.print(opt.get().getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ...}
  }
}
```

И запуск

```
BlockingQueue<Optional<File>> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
FileManager.parseListPath(...., q);
Consumer c = new Consumer(q);
new Thread(c).start();
```

Comment: аргументы в put для LinkedBlockingQueue должны быть @NotNull

Comment: @JustCat вы правы. Переделал на `Optional`